# Parsing error: Unexpected token click_action

Tags: json, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently I am working on push notifications using firebase-cloud-messaging . The token click_action is still supported, but still I am getting this error.
My code is 
,

The error on cmd (Firebase CLI) is,

```
notification: {
    title: "Notification from" + from_name,
    body: from_message,
    sound: "default"
    click_action: "com.example.tysf_trial"
}
```

This error is encountered when deployed,

```
 43:5  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token click_action

? 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-05T19_43_05_08
1Z-debug.log
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mfirebase
-tools←[24m\node_modules\←[4mcross-env←[24m\node_modules\←[4mcross-spawn←[24m\li
b\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mfirebase-
tools←[24m\node_modules\←[4mcross-env←[24m\node_modules\←[4mcross-spawn←[24m\lib
\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mf
irebase-tools←[24m\node_modules\←[4mcross-env←[24m\node_modules\←[4mcross-spawn←
[24m\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:1
2)←[39m
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mf
irebase-tools←[24m\node_modules\←[4mcross-env←[24m\node_modules\←[4mcross-spawn←
[24m\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:1
2)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
  errno: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
  syscall: ←[32m'spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint'←[39m,
  path: ←[32m'npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint'←[39m,
  spawnargs: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the hole working code for me it working with me yesterday... ^_^

```
    'use-strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document
("NotifyUsers/{user_id}/Notification/{notification_id}")
.onWrite((change, context) => {

const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;


return admin.firestore().collection("NotifyUsers")
.doc(user_id).collection("Notification").doc(notification_id)
.get().then(queryResult => {

    const {from:from_user_id, message:from_message} = queryResult.data();


    const from_data = admin.firestore().collection("NotifyUsers")
    .doc(from_user_id).get();
    const to_data = admin.firestore().collection("NotifyUsers")
    .doc(user_id).get();


    return Promise.all([from_data, to_data, from_message , from_user_id]);
    // added from_message so it's available in the next .then
})
.then(([from_data, to_data, from_message, from_user_id]) => { // added from_message

    const from_name = from_data.data().name;

    const {name:to_name, token_id} = to_data.data();

    console.log("From: " + from_name + " | To : " + to_name +"from:" +from_user_id);

    const payload = {
        "notification" : {
            "title" : "Notification From : " + from_name,
            "body" : from_message,
            "icon" : 'default',
            "click_action": 'return.to.NotificationActivity'
        },
        "data": {
            "from_user_id" : from_user_id, 
            "message" : from_message
        }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload);
})
.then(result => {
    return console.log("Notification Sent");
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a comma after the `sound:` line:

```
notification: {
    title: "Notification from" + from_name,
    body: from_message,
    sound: "default", // here
    click_action: "com.example.tysf_trial"
}
```